# Turbolinks and Scrollspy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, scrollspy

I've followed [this tutorial](http://www.codingeverything.com/2014/02/BootstrapDocsSideBar.html?showComment=1495287495880#c3601123373729090730) to duplicate the side menu from the boostrap docs.

Everything seems to work great, but once an anchor tag is clicked from the submenu, the current submenu collapses.  Scrolling to the next submenu section will open the submenu back up and it will work properly again.  However, scrolling back to the clicked anchor tag will collapse the submenu again.

I've confirmed that turning turbolinks off will fix this, but I was hoping to address this while keeping turbolinks.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I've not been able to reproduce the behaviour you're experiencing, so if you have an example you can share, that'd help.

You are probably experiencing a bug with the way Turbolinks handles same-page anchors. It currently reloads the page, then scrolls to the element, rather than just scrolling to the element. This bug has been noted in the Turbolinks repository: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/75. One possible solution is to prevent Turbolinks reloading the page on same-page anchor clicks:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:click', function (event) {
  if (event.target.getAttribute('href').charAt(0) === '#') {
    return event.preventDefault()
  }
})
```

The slight downside is that this might cause back button issues. Otherwise you may want to experiment with calling `.scrollspy('refresh')` on the relevant selection once the page has loaded (see: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy-methods).